# How to accomplish this design in css?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

First im a newbie in css so please bear with me :D

I want to create something like this :

[image]

The image is vertical-middle from the text. I tried everything i know and doing much trial, but this is what i get :

[image]

**I have some problem with the width, because i want to create a fluid web (with %).**

This is my current code :

meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

html

```
<div id="header">
            <a href="JakartaWikiMall.html"><img src="images/SearchByMall/btnBack.png" /></a>
            <p>Search by Mall</p>
</div>
```

css

```
#header{
    background: #e8c07a;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5% 5% 10% 5%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    /*show background*/
    overflow: auto;
}

#header img {
    float:left;
    width: 15%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* margin-top: -5%;  */
}

#header p {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

What should i do?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :D

Comment: See you are all set, only you have to do is to add some line-height to #header p element.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a bigger line-height on the text the space above and below it will grow evenly top and bottom, centring your text vertically.

Say your text is 12px, setting a line-height of 30px or 2.4(no units) should do the trick.

I'm not 100% certain what will happen to your image's position without testing it, but I would set the #header to position relative, put some left padding on it and set the img position to absolute, left: -10px, top: 50%;, margin-top: -5px (whatever half the height of your image is);

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good starting point for what you're trying to do. http://jsbin.com/inefuj/4/